# Using a typeclass to access fields of similar data types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, graph, polymorphism, typeclass

I am in the process of working on some graph problems in Haskell. In the middle of my work, I decided that I wanted to be able to represent edge colors within a graph data type. So I started with edges: Edges could be either colored or uncolored. Here's a quick mock-up of what I was thinking about. Keep in mind, I'm aware that there are terrible flaws in this code.

```
data BasicEdge v w = BasicEdge { b_endpoints :: (v,v), b_weight :: w}
data ColoredEdge v w c = ColoredEdge { c_endpoints :: (v,v), c_weight :: w, color :: c}

class Edge e where
    endpoints :: e -> (v,v)
    weight :: e -> w

instance Edge (BasicEdge v w) where
    endpoints = b_endpoints
    weight = b_weight

instance Edge (ColoredEdge v w c) where
    endpoints = c_endpoints
    weight = c_weight
```

Problem 1: `v` and `w` in BasicEdge are different type variables than `v` and `w` in ColoredEdge. Thus, attempting to access them in a polymorphic manner is preposterous.

Problem 2: return values in the Edge class definition are free type variables, so they cannot be matched with the return values of `b_endpoints` and `c_endpoints`, etc.

I do need the type variables - Vertices could be characters, strings, integers, etc..  Edge weights could be any sort of number (Floats are helpful for some problems). Colors could even be a constructed data type.

Is there an "idiomatic" way to do this in the language? It seems that this is a basic type of polymorphism, but I am struggling to understand how to implement it.

Thanks in advance for your help, and please understand that I have spent the past day trying to search on the internet for guidance. It is difficult to structure a search query for this problem.

Comment: Ask yourself: How is the compiler supposed to know what type `v` is?

Comment: I'm aware that this is an issue - see "Problem 1" and "Problem 2" in my question. The challenge was finding a good solution to the issue.

Comment: Type families would be ideal in this case, then. Look at the `GHC.Exts` package's `IsList` class if you want to see what I mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your type class can be fixed by including the type parameters `v` and `w` in the class definition.

```
class Edge e where
    endpoints :: e v w -> (v,v)
    weight :: e v w -> w
```

Now `e` has the kind `* -> * -> *` meaning that it needs to be a type that takes two additional type parameters and these parameters are then used in `endpoints` and `weight` to actually link the result type to the type of the edge.

However, you need to tweak your `ColoredEdge` type a bit so that `v` and `w` are the last two parameters, so

```
data BasicEdge v w = BasicEdge { b_endpoints :: (v,v), b_weight :: w}
data ColoredEdge c v w = ColoredEdge { c_endpoints :: (v,v), c_weight :: w, color :: c}
```

Now you can define the instances as

```
instance Edge BasicEdge where
    endpoints = b_endpoints
    weight = b_weight

instance Edge (ColoredEdge c) where
    endpoints = c_endpoints
    weight = c_weight
```

Another option is to use the `TypeFamilies` language extension and make the vertex and weight types associated type synonyms in the `Edge` class. That way the order to type parameters in the instance types becomes irrelevant.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class Edge e where
    type Vertex e
    type Weight e

    endpoints :: e -> (Vertex e, Vertex e)
    weight :: e -> Weight e

instance Edge (BasicEdge v w) where
    type Vertex (BasicEdge v w) = v
    type Weight (BasicEdge v w) = w

    endpoints = b_endpoints
    weight = b_weight

instance Edge (ColoredEdge v w c) where
    type Vertex (ColoredEdge v w c) = v
    type Weight (ColoredEdge v w c) = w

    endpoints = c_endpoints
    weight = c_weight
```

However, usually type classes are not the best solution for this kind of polymorphism. I would simply include an extra parameter in your `Edge` type for any additional data, as in

```
data Edge v w d = Edge { endpoints :: (v,v), weight :: w, edgeData :: d }
```

Now you can put color in `d` or a record that contains multiple fields of data for an edge and still query the shape of the graph in a generic way.

Your original edge types could now be represented with the type synonyms

```
type BasicEdge   v w   = Edge v w ()
type ColoredEdge v w c = Edge v w c
```

Comment: I started writing an answer, and I was so busy describing fundeps and ATs that I completely missed the obvious Haskell 2010 solution. Well played!

Comment: Wow. I was so upset with the thought of an unused type variable to a simple edge, and for some reason it didn't occur to me that I could just hide it with a type synonym. While your first answer makes sense, I'd rather go the minimalist route - as you said, using type classes in this situation doesn't feel right. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: I Love type-families soo much. Great answer, great example.